# I added all the recommended rules from the eslint docs to my .eslintrc.js file and they all throw 'Definition for rule was not found'

Tags: typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

Here's the contents of my `.eslintrc.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        project: 'tsconfig.json',
        sourceType: 'module'
    },
    plugins: ['@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'],
    extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:prettier/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking'
    ],
    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true,
        jest: true
    },
    ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js'],
    rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/for-direction': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/getter-return': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-async-promise-executor': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-await-in-loop': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-class-assign': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-compare-neg-zero': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-cond-assign': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-const-assign': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-constant-condition': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-constructor-return': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-control-regex': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-debugger': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-dupe-args': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-dupe-class-members': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-dupe-else-if': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-dupe-keys': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-duplicate-case': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-duplicate-imports': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-character-class': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-pattern': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-ex-assign': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-fallthrough': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-func-assign': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-import-assign': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-inner-declarations': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-invalid-regexp': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-irregular-whitespace': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-loss-of-precision': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-misleading-character-class': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-new-symbol': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-obj-calls': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-promise-executor-return': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-prototype-builtins': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-self-assign': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-self-compare': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-setter-return': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-sparse-arrays': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-template-curly-in-string': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-this-before-super': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-undef': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unexpected-multiline': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unmodified-loop-condition': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unreachable': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unreachable-loop': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-finally': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-negation': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-optional-chaining': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-labels': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-private-class-members': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-useless-backreference': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/require-atomic-updates': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/use-isnan ': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/valid-typeof': 'error',
        curly: 'error'
    }
};
```

package.json contents:

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,libs}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "lint:ci": "eslint \"{src,libs}/**/*.ts\"",
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.12.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.12.1",
    "eslint": "8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
...
```

Full error list:

```
 1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/for-direction' was not found                    @typescript-eslint/for-direction
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/getter-return' was not found                    @typescript-eslint/getter-return
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-async-promise-executor' was not found        @typescript-eslint/no-async-promise-executor
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-await-in-loop' was not found                 @typescript-eslint/no-await-in-loop
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-class-assign' was not found                  @typescript-eslint/no-class-assign
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-compare-neg-zero' was not found              @typescript-eslint/no-compare-neg-zero
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-cond-assign' was not found                   @typescript-eslint/no-cond-assign
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-const-assign' was not found                  @typescript-eslint/no-const-assign
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-constant-condition' was not found            @typescript-eslint/no-constant-condition
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-constructor-return' was not found            @typescript-eslint/no-constructor-return
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-control-regex' was not found                 @typescript-eslint/no-control-regex
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-debugger' was not found                      @typescript-eslint/no-debugger
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-dupe-args' was not found                     @typescript-eslint/no-dupe-args
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-dupe-else-if' was not found                  @typescript-eslint/no-dupe-else-if
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-dupe-keys' was not found                     @typescript-eslint/no-dupe-keys
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-duplicate-case' was not found                @typescript-eslint/no-duplicate-case
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-character-class' was not found         @typescript-eslint/no-empty-character-class
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-pattern' was not found                 @typescript-eslint/no-empty-pattern
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-ex-assign' was not found                     @typescript-eslint/no-ex-assign
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-fallthrough' was not found                   @typescript-eslint/no-fallthrough
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-func-assign' was not found                   @typescript-eslint/no-func-assign
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-import-assign' was not found                 @typescript-eslint/no-import-assign
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-inner-declarations' was not found            @typescript-eslint/no-inner-declarations
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-invalid-regexp' was not found                @typescript-eslint/no-invalid-regexp
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-irregular-whitespace' was not found          @typescript-eslint/no-irregular-whitespace
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-misleading-character-class' was not found    @typescript-eslint/no-misleading-character-class
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-new-symbol' was not found                    @typescript-eslint/no-new-symbol
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-obj-calls' was not found                     @typescript-eslint/no-obj-calls
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-promise-executor-return' was not found       @typescript-eslint/no-promise-executor-return
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-prototype-builtins' was not found            @typescript-eslint/no-prototype-builtins
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-self-assign' was not found                   @typescript-eslint/no-self-assign
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-self-compare' was not found                  @typescript-eslint/no-self-compare
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-setter-return' was not found                 @typescript-eslint/no-setter-return
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-sparse-arrays' was not found                 @typescript-eslint/no-sparse-arrays
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-template-curly-in-string' was not found      @typescript-eslint/no-template-curly-in-string
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-this-before-super' was not found             @typescript-eslint/no-this-before-super
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-undef' was not found                         @typescript-eslint/no-undef
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unexpected-multiline' was not found          @typescript-eslint/no-unexpected-multiline
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unmodified-loop-condition' was not found     @typescript-eslint/no-unmodified-loop-condition
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unreachable' was not found                   @typescript-eslint/no-unreachable
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unreachable-loop' was not found              @typescript-eslint/no-unreachable-loop
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-finally' was not found                @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-finally
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-negation' was not found               @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-negation
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-optional-chaining' was not found      @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-optional-chaining
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-labels' was not found                 @typescript-eslint/no-unused-labels
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-private-class-members' was not found  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-private-class-members
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/no-useless-backreference' was not found         @typescript-eslint/no-useless-backreference
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/require-atomic-updates' was not found           @typescript-eslint/require-atomic-updates
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/use-isnan ' was not found                       @typescript-eslint/use-isnan 
  1:1  error  Definition for rule '@typescript-eslint/valid-typeof' was not found                     @typescript-eslint/valid-typeof
```

I don't really know what else I need to add to my configuration to make `eslint` work with the recommended rules. I've been pouring over the docs and it feels like I'm just trying things at random to try to get the errors to disappear.

Answer (score 3):

The error comes from ESLint thinking that the TypeScript rule is a missing rule.

Although your `package.json` specifies the correct version for `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser`, double-check that your project is indeed using the correct version.

Run the following commands:

```
npm ls @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
npm ls @typescript-eslint/parser
```

If they are not both `5.12.1`, try to update them to that version.

```
npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.12.1
npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint/parser@5.12.1
```

***Note:*** [according to the author](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin), if you installed ESLint globally, then install `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` globally as well (use `-g` instead of `--save-dev`).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm no stranger to node projects so doing a clean `npm install` was something I had already tried. I did `npm ls` and got the correct version for both the `eslint-plugin` and the `parser` entries. Additionally, I never use the `npm install -g` flag.